# How to run js script on button click

Tags: javascript

How to run this script with button click?

I don't know how to write code for a button and connect it with the code below.

```
<div id="rez" style="display: none;">BRAVO!</div> 

<script>
function showElement(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

window.onload = function ShowHide() {
    var legend = document.getElementById("LEGEND").innerHTML;

    if(legend.indexOf("100%") != -1) showElement("rez");

}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you google it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

a simple google search will yield answers to this kind of questions: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: I find this on google but i dont know where to put myfunction() in scrpit